# split string into list but keeping the symbols

Tags: python, regex, string

I want to split the words in a string but keeping symbols separately too.

```
s = "Hello world. This-is-foo! I love you"
```

the output should be

```
out: ["Hello", "world", ".", "This", "-", "is", "-", "foo", "!", "I", "love", "you"]
```

I tried:

```
re.split('(\W)', s)
```

But this is the output:

```
['Hello',
 ' ',
 'world',
 '.',
 '',
 ' ',
 'This',
 '-',
 'is',
 '-',
 'foo',
 '!',
 '',
 ' ',
 'I',
 ' ',
 'love',
 ' ',
 'you']
```

As you can see the spaces are left there. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 3):

You may use this regex with `findall` in `python`:

```
>>> s = "Hello world. This-is-foo! I love you"
>>> print ( re.findall( r'\w+|[^\s\w]+', s) )
['Hello', 'world', '.', 'This', '-', 'is', '-', 'foo', '!', 'I', 'love', 'you']
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/cqm6O7/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `\w+`: Match 1 or more word characters
- `|`: OR
- `[^\s\w]+`; Match 1 or more non-word and non-whitespace characters

Comment: [^\s\w]+ can be replaced to \S

Comment: Nope, they are different. If input is `"Hello world. This-is-foo!! I love you"` then `\S` will give `!` and `!` separately but this one will keep both `!!` in single element.

Comment: Nice spot! The OP can choose then a precise behaviour on dealing with multiple symbols

Comment: @user12195705: Did this work out?

Answer (score 2):

This regex should work:

```
re.findall(r'\w+|\S', s)
```

This represents words and no-whitespace characters.

Code:

```
import re
s = "Hello world. This-is-foo! I love you"
print(re.findall(r"\w+|[^\w\s]+", s))
```

Output:

```
['Hello', 'world', '.', 'This', '-', 'is', '-', 'foo', '!', 'I', 'love', 'you']
```

Comment: But @AlexMTX has already posted this answer 7 min before you.

Comment: Yea I noticed that later @anubhava

Answer (score 1):

You can match the words `\w+` or the non-words `\W+` (notice the uppercase):

```py
import re

s = "Hello world. This-is-foo! I love you"

print(re.findall(r"\w+|\W+", s))
```

You get:

```py
['Hello', ' ', 'world', '. ', 'This', '-', 'is', '-', 'foo', '! ', 'I', ' ', 'love', ' ', 'you']
```

**EDIT**

If you want to avoid the white spaces, you can do:

```py
import re

s = "Hello world. This-is-foo! I love you"

print(re.findall(r"\w+|[^\w\s]+", s))
```

You get:

```
['Hello', 'world', '.', 'This', '-', 'is', '-', 'foo', '!', 'I', 'love', 'you']
```

Comment: But.....your result is as the same as the OP's.

Comment: I believe OP doesn't want whitespace `' '` etc in output.

Comment: @anubhava, You're right. The OP has to use the class `[^\w\s]+` to match the non-words without whitepsace.

Answer (score 1):

All words and no-whitespace characters

```py
re.findall(r'\w+|\S', s)
```

Answer (score 0):

After that you may filter the spaces using a list comprehension..

 
`s = [x for x in re.split('(\W)', s) if x != " "]`

Testing this solution with %%timeit magic shows that it is almost as fast as the most popular answer

Comment: using list comprehension + regex, it's make it overloading

Comment: Can you elaborate a little on what you mean with overloading please

Comment: regex is time consuming operation, and you are using the list comprehension + string matching with it , so this is making this code overload/process more data and increase time complexity